# Access deployed contracts on Ganache local blockchain - BrownieEnvironmentError: Functionality not available in local environment

Tags: contract-deployment, ganache, brownie, ganache-cli, access

Using a generic *SimpleStorage.sol* contract and a *deploy.py* I'm able to create a contract on a Ganache local blockchain and access it during execution. On `brownie console` is possible to do the same step by step. My problem rises as soon as the execution terminates or the console is closed as the contract I just deployed seems unreachable. If I reopen the console and I run `SimpleStorage` the output given is an empty list (The contract I just deployed should be in the list but it's not).. so I try running `Contract("contract_address")` But the result is the following error:

*BrownieEnvironmentError: Functionality not available in local environment*

Is there any workaround for this or am I thinking wrong and I can't actually access old deployed contracts on Ganache with brownie? If so can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tips I was able to solve so I'll post the simple solution I found.

So the problem was actually that I was deploying on a Development network and so brownie by default didn't save the deployments. So the solution was to create a new Ganache chain under Ethereum with the following command:

`brownie networks add Ethereum ganache-local host=http://127.0.0.1:8545 chainid=5777`

You can ensure the network has been correctly created by using `brownie networks list` which should output something like (truncated to Ethereum networks):

```
Ethereum
```

├─Mainnet (Infura): mainnet
├─Ropsten (Infura): ropsten
├─Rinkeby (Infura): rinkeby
├─Goerli (Infura): goerli
├─Kovan (Infura): kovan
└─ganache-local: ganache-local

After that you want brownie to use that new chain as default so I added the following lines into the *brownie.config.yaml* file:

```
networks:
  default: ganache-local
```

This way you ensure that brownie actually keeps track of the deployments. Hopefully I can be of help to somebody. For further information take a look at  this resource to understand better brownie’s behavior when it comes to the ganache chain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239681